Method to subdivide ngon in geometry nodes?
Is there any way to subdivide ngon or convert in to quads in geometry nodes?.
In picture blow if subdivide produces crossing edges.



The problem here is that the star does not have any internal geometry, so that subdivision would be possible without errors.
Therefore, instead of creating the desired shape with Curve to Mesh, you would first have to create the base mesh with the necessary geometry and then extrude it upwards.
The Node Fill Curve helps you here, as it generates a mesh from a curve with corresponding triangulated faces.
Something like this:

